# Error connecting to wireless network from command line

Tags: command-line, wireless, chromebook, chrubuntu

I have Chrubuntu installed on an Acer Chromebook 13 and would like to connect to my home wireless network. I was able identify the card with `iwconfig` and make sure the network is reachable with `iwlist mlan0 scan`.

I then followed the [instructions at the Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WiFiHowTo#Using_the_command_Line) to connect:

```
$ iwconfig mlan0 mode managed
$ iwconfig mlan0 channel 11
$ iwconfig mlan0 essid 8ef11c
```

None of these commands returns errors message, however, when I try to set the password I get this back:

```
$ sudo iwconfig mlan0 key s:999999999
Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A):
    SET failed on device mlan0 ; Invalid argument.
```

After that any attempt to connect returns the usual:

`connect: Network is unreachable`

Any hints on what I may be doing wrong?

**Update:** Answering the request from [Pilot6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690211/error-connecting-to-wireless-network-from-command-line?noredirect=1#comment1007434_690211):

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci
lspci: Cannot find any working access method.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: According to the documentation, the encryption is done like `sudo iwconfig mlan0 key s:999999999`

Comment: The `key` argument was missing, I have to copy this by hand from the chromebook screen.